# stop mithrill redraw on first action

Tags: mithril.js

I'm writing a single page application using mithril. The page loads some data from the server using m.request() in the oninit of the main component:

```
var root = document.getElementById("main");
var Data = {
        fetch: function () {
            m.request({
                method: "GET",
                url: "/api/read"
            })
                .then(function (items) {
                    // init models with data
                });
    }
}

var Home = {
    oninit: Data.fetch,
    view: function (vnode) {
        return m("div", [components]);
    }
}

m.route(root,
    "/",
    {
        "/": Home
    });
```

The data is a huge json, the page is to help edit the json by ensuring that certain foreign key constraints are met, and visualising it a bit better. Everything works as expected until a call a component that actually adds a brand new entry to any of the json objects i have. At this stage the page reloads, and the data gets fetched again, so I lose all the changes. It only ever happens once though and only on this call:

```
jsonModel[propertyName].push(JSON.parse(newObject))
```

After this first redraw I can modify the page as much as I like, this issue will not happen again. I can even refresh without it occurring.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong in my structure? Can this refresh be prevented?

Comment: Without seeing more code it's tricky to know for sure.I'd recommend doing initial data fetches like that outside of a component entirely and having it return the promise. Then any later methods that need access to that data can call `.then()` on the promise and be assured that the data is loaded before they try to operate on it.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what the problem might be from this snapshot. You could certainly get a lot of qualified help if you put the question to the Mithril chatroom: https://gitter.im/mithriljs/mithril.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to call `event.preventDefault()` in the `onclick` handler for the `<button>` then, to prevent it from auto-submitting the form.

There's a few other approaches you could take, but that'll be the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue but the actual error was not included in the question: the component firing the action is a button. This button was placed in a form tag and for some reason only triggered a submit once. [Here's the code](https://flems.io/#0=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-Xly3tn3gvvIqZKYL4M3JicOkxDEPQ+7AJI9DUFAEDUAA1tO158scvShjUJiyma8r7iYACyoYYDkGBwNQ0RNO4niSCYACCYapumTSjI2Y4Bs2Vxxow1RxAko4rCYqggmCYpvPxJhbDI7YwE2LSUCAcDyPWfIIH4AAMiAqQAtAAzOSiCUh4XggJgOB4DKcBBMaoTMH4HijFQMFoHBymoEZPh4FgrpDOQVCQuQfhwoiyKqAM8JwTkJ5YKoHlfF5AAC5L4AlABsUWedA+CBLJxB8PCvhydQQzwuE7h2a5Jl+DcYDaoQGZoAAyuknDRRU5kPB4QA) that would reproduce the issue.

Interestingly, when trying it in Edge it almost always refreshes. I would still be interested in why it only does it once on Chrome if anyone knows?